# The Bottom Border of a simple Windows Application keeps disappearing and reaapearing when resizing the window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Here's a simple Win32 Application that I copied from the official MSDN docs ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program)):

```cpp
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";
    
    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);



            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_DESKTOP+1));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The only difference is I used `COLOR_DESKTOP` instead of `COLOR_WINDOW` in `FillRect()` (this problem occurs in both the cases).

Whenever I resize the window, the bottom border keeps disappearing and then reappearing as I resize it further. Can anyone tell what's happening?

Here's GIF to show the bottom border disappearing when resizing:

[image: gif]

Comment: I can't see this defect on my build. With `(COLOR_DESKTOP+1)`, both window AND border are black, so I see no border. What did you change to make yours green?

Comment: Is the DPI setting for your display something other than 100%?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm by DPI settings I assume you mean scaling? Currently my display resolution 1080p at 125% scaling. The interesting thing is the problem does not occur at 100% scaling , but does occur for any other scaling (125%, 150%).

Comment: @VladFeinstein I changed the Color from `Personalization` -> `Colors` -> Selecting the `Title Bars and Window Borders`. Also, I have my `Window colours` set to green.

Comment: @VladFeinstein by the way, this problem also occurs if I use `COLOR_WINDOW` instead of `COLOR_DESKTOP`, so I assume this is not really due to that. It could be due to scaling as mentioned in a previous reply but I don't get why would it affect only this window application. Any other window border such as that of File Explorer or Command Prompt window don't show this behavior.

Comment: I can only speculate, but at 125% scaling, with rounding, the client area may be 1 off, and your `FillRect` can paint over the bottom border. I would expect it to paint over the right one too, occasionally.

Comment: @vla The `HDC` you get from `BeginPaint` has its clipping region automatically set to the update region. The update region cannot include anything outside the client area. There is no way to accidentally render over the border.

Comment: @IInspectable could that clipped region suffer from that rounding error?

Comment: @vla All supported scaling factors can be expressed as finite sums of powers of two. I don't see an opportunity for rounding errors when multiplying by 1.25, for example. I guess the issue is rooted in the compositor, that—to my knowledge—uses a coordinate system that's incompatible with Windows' native coordinate system (the former is endpoint-inclusive, with the latter being endpoint-exclusive). Mapping between them is surprisingly non-trivial. With that, the only solution would be to go back to Windows 7 and disable desktop composition.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you could try to enable DPI awareness: `Property -> Manifest Tool ->Input and Output -> DPI Awareness`.

[image]

Comment: @keishi May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.